# Get document objects from firebase collection

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

Just started working with firebase cloud and I'm stuck. I expect the solution to be an easy one, but I could not solve it so far.

I created a project (https://github.com/DragosB88/vending-machine) using mockups, but now I want to use firebase. So I created a project on firebase cloud, and created there a collection and a document of objects with:

```js
// SET FIRESTORE PRODUCTS - function inside service
setDBProducts(data) {
       this.firestore
           .collection('vendingProducts') // collection name on Cloud Firestore
           .doc('products')               // document name on Cloud Firestore
           .set(Object.assign({}, data)); // it only accepts objects, thus arrays must be converted
    }
```

which worked just fine:

[firebase data](https://ibb.co/BtSXnSm)

The problem is that when I am trying to retrieve the data, I get different objects (depending on the requests I make) that do not contain any of the data that is on firebase.

```js
  // GET FIRESTORE PRODUCTS - service function
  getDBProducts() {
    return this.firestore.collection('vendingProducts').doc('products').get();
  }
  
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------
  // GET FIRESTORE PRODUCTS - component function inside constructor

 this.dbProducts = ProductsService.getDBProducts().subscribe(
    (res) => (this.dbProducts = res)
 );
 // this.dbProducts = ProductsService.getDBProducts();
 console.log('DATABASE PRODUCTS: ', this.dbProducts);
```

[this is what I receive upon subscribing](https://ibb.co/MsKR88G)

How can I get the products from firebase?
(btw, I am also new to observables)

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Any code that needs access to the data, needs to be in your `subscribe` callback (or be called from there).

In your current code, by the time your `console.log('DATABASE PRODUCTS: ', this.dbProducts)` runs, the `this.dbProducts = res` hasn't executed yet.

So this is one solution:

```
 this.dbProducts = ProductsService.getDBProducts().subscribe((res) => {
    this.dbProducts = res;
    console.log('DATABASE PRODUCTS: ', this.dbProducts);
 });
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that was a slip on my part. But I still this does not retrieve the products, but the following object: https://ibb.co/25Sn3Nn
If i filter the console for any of the products in the firebase db, I don't see any of them.